# Concatenating struct in byte array

Tags: c++, c++20

I want to concatenate two structs. The problem is that I cannot convert that struct to a `std::span`, because span's constructor doesn't support `void*`. I'm using the same concat function to concatenate `std::vector<uint8_t>` as well, so any changes made to that function, shouldn't affect it. If it's possible to convert the struct to `vector<uint8_t>`, I will be able to change `std::span<uint8_t>` to vector of the same. How can I do that?

```cpp
address_t address{};
memcpy(address.country, country, sizeof country);
memcpy(address.city, city, sizeof city);
memcpy(address.state, state, sizeof state);
address.zip_code = zip_code;

...

const auto& a = reinterpret_cast<void*>(&address);

auto c = utils::concat(a, b);
```

#### Snippet

```cpp
__declspec(align(16))
typedef struct
{
    std::wchar_t country[30];
    std::wchar_t city[50];
    std::wchar_t state[50];
    std::uint32_t zip_code;
} address_t;

namespace utils
{
    inline std::vector<std::uint8_t> concat(const std::span<std::uint8_t>& a)
    {
        return std::vector<std::uint8_t>(a.data(), a.data() + a.size());
    }
    
    template <typename... Args>
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> concat(const std::span<std::uint8_t>& a, Args&... args)
    {
        auto vec = std::vector<std::uint8_t>(a.data(), a.data() + a.size());
        (vec.insert(vec.end(), args.begin(), args.end()), ...);

        return vec;
    }
}
```

Comment: a struct is not a vector, though. What do you think you'd get if you concatted one struct onto another, other than an access violation?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey, but a struct is literally bytes next to each other with some spacing in between which is the alignment. Why would it be not possible?

Comment: why not just reinterpret to uint8_t* instead of void*?  But you'll need to provide the length of the data at some point.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey, works too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a way to reinterpret an `address` as a span:

```cpp
auto to_span(address const& a) -> std::span<uint8_t const> {
    return {(uint8_t const*)&a, sizeof(a)};
}
```

And then the rest of your stuff just works:

```cpp
auto c = utils::concat(to_span(address), to_span(other_address));
```

This can be generalized to support trivially copyable types.

---

Your `concat` currently takes parameters as `const std::span<std::uint8_t>&`. You typically want to take `span` by value (it's a small, trivially copyable type, and you almost never care about the *identity* of the `span`). Additionally, when you're not modifying the contents of the `span` (as you're not here), you want to ensure that it's a `span` over `const` data.

That is, your parameters should have type `std::span<uint8_t const>`.

This ensures that you're not modifying through the `span` (which is important and allows you to pass immutable things, like my `to_span` above) whereas taking by `const&` only protects you from modifying the `span` itself (which is not important at all).

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a difference between `const std::vector<std::uint8_t>&` and `const std::vector<std::uint8_t const>&` tho?

Comment: @nop Yes: the latter is ill-formed and the former is not (you can't have a `vector<T const>`)

Comment: thank you a lot! Summarized, these objects that we care about its value like `std::span`, they should be `const std::span<std::uint8_t const>` alike and the others that we want to prevent copies, they should be `const std::vector<std::uint8_t>&`, right?

Comment: @nop Yes. Because `vector` owns its data (copying is expensive,and it is deep `const`) and `span` does not (copying is cheap and it is shallow `const`)

Comment: Thank you once again! Great answer, great explanation!

Comment: Barry are you not using std::byte just because you are matching OP, or you actually prefer the uint8 for this usecase?